# How to create an Angular 2 canvas-based component that responds to being resized?

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-canvas

I want to create a component whose view is simply a canvas element. I want this component to:

- Fill whatever element it is placed with the canvas
- Determine its width and height during its initialization process
- Know when it has been resized, figuring out its new height and width, and responding appropriately.

I figure I can achieve the first part by specifying the width and height of the canvas in my component's template as 100%, like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'canvas-component',
  template:'<canvas style="width:100%; height:100%"></canvas>'
})
```

But I have no idea how to go about the second or third parts.

The ultimate goal is to be able to draw shapes in the canvas that take up the same relative size of the canvas, regardless of its size. As an example, I'd want to draw a circle with a diameter of 3/4 the width of the canvas - so if the canvas grows or shrinks, the circle should be re-drawn, growing or shrinking as well.

I don't know if it matters, but I'm making the web app in Typescript.

Does anyone know of a good way of achieving this? I'm looking for doing it the most "Angular way" possible, since this is a personal project I'm using to learn Angular 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The browser doesn't provide much here and therefore Angular2 can't as well. What you can do is polling the size of the parent and the current element.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know how I would have the component go about polling its own size? Would it be proper to do that in an event maybe - like listening for the window to resize or something?

Comment: Window.onResize might be sufficient depending on your requirements. If you for example have a splitter component, then moving the splitter would not cause resize events but your component might still resize. Also adding removing HTML can cause resize for other elements. Perhaps checking in `ngDoCheck` might work. I'd start with this and if it causes too much CPU usage try to further optimize.

Answer (score 7):

This is far from an "answer" but should get you going:

**Component**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('myCanvas') canvas;

  onResize() {
    // Not a good thing to do but will get you going.
    // I need to look into the Renderer service instead.
    const canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;

    // These don't change (canvas intrinsic dimensions)
    const canvasWidth = canvasElement.width;
    const canvasHeight = canvasElement.height;

    // These will change (scaling applied by the style)
    const computedStyles = getComputedStyle(canvasElement);
    const computedWidth = computedStyles.width;
    const computedHeight = computedStyles.height;
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<div (window:resize)="onResize()"></div>
<canvas #myCanvas style="width:100%; height:100%" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That looks like a good setup to a solution, but getting the height and width of the canvas is the part that's stumping me. I'm not sure how to find those values, or the values of the width and height of its parent.

Comment: I see... You are trying find the height and width of the canvas instead of setting it. I'll edit the answer to give you some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way: introduce a parent container in the template and bind to it's dimensions.

In **canvas-panel.component.html**

```html
<div #canvasWrapper class="canvas-wrapper" (window:resize)="draw()">
  <canvas id="wfcanvas" #canvasId
     [height]="canvasWrapper.offsetHeight" 
     [width]="canvasWrapper.offsetWidth">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

In **canvas-panel.component.css**

```css
.canvas-wrapper {
  width: 94%;
  height: 128px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

In **canvas-panel.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas-panel',
  templateUrl: './canvas-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas-panel.component.scss']
})
export class CanvasPanelComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('canvasId') canvasRef: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  draw() {
    let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D =
      this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

    console.log("canvas size: ", ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the canvas resize function.

In component.html:

```html
<canvas #mycanvas class="canvasc" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

In component.ts:

```js
// Somewhere above your class constructor
@ViewChild('mycanvas') mycanvas: any;
public ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
     
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.ctx = this.mycanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.mycanvas.nativeElement.onresize = this.Function;
}
```